# Java method sees inheritance correctly in one case but not another, what's the culprit?

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

Can't find the reason why a method does not see inheritance. What am I missing here?

```
public class Rate extends BaseResource
public class GenericQuote extends BaseResource
public class Payment extends GenericQuote

public void handleMediationErrors(BaseResource response)
```

`handleMediationErrors(myRate)` **<-- works** 
`handleMediationErrors(myPayment)` **<-- fails at compile time tells me that it expects `BaseResource` not `Payment`**

Comment: Are they extending the same `BaseResource`?

Comment: My guess is you are missing something important.  This sort of thing can happen with generics but not in the example you gave.

Comment: Please give a [short, self-contained example that demonstrates your problem](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Voted to close.  The question is not answerable without an SSCE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the example you've given - perhaps you're using a different `BaseResource` in one of the classes (importing a different one or declaring it separately elsewhere - this can cause confusion!)

To prove it, this example compiles perfectly:

```
class BaseResource {}
class Rate extends BaseResource {}
class GenericQuote extends BaseResource {}
class Payment extends GenericQuote {}

public class Test {

    public void handleMediationErrors(BaseResource response) {}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test().handleMediationErrors(new Payment());
        new Test().handleMediationErrors(new Rate());
        new Test().handleMediationErrors(new GenericQuote());
        new Test().handleMediationErrors(new Payment());
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that would work OK. Try calling Payment myPayment

Comment: I think this has to do with something like super.super.method() calling problem

Comment: As demonstrated, still works with a payment as expected. I think we'll need to see a SSCCE example that demonstrates your issue in order to help.

Comment: Problem was, I wasn't importing the correct payment. Damn it "Organize Imports".